# How to calculate (summarize) proper Percentage within 24h (to not exceed 100%)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013, array-formulas

Topic sounds simple but the task that I am interested in is not!

So, I got a set of measurement data that are changing per day, with more instances within one day!  So as you can see for 07.02.2019 you got 5x instances that are changing (system changes) with different Time difference.  Well that is the point, I need to have it in percentage but within 24h! not like you can see on this example over 100% what is nonsense.

The data itself are recording the data constantly, and system change is automatic. Sometimes you can have 1-2 instances per day, and sometimes over 5x..

I did some calcs using `=mod` for Time difference `(d2-d1,1)` and `=sumifs` for giving me SUM of one day per system, but it is wrong, because it is taking also time difference from previous day and summing it....

Is there any way to be limited to 24h max? not to calculate time difference when is happening over 24th hour??

I hope you got my concern.. this is only small part of complete picture, there are more events where I have over 100%....

I mean there is a way to put =`MIN(1;I2)` but I am only limited to 100% exactly..dont know if that is right approach.

[image: Data]

[image: Chart]

[image: Calculate]

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to find the total % time difference split by DAY, or split by SYSTEM AND DAY?

Comment: @Gravitate Good point! Sorry didnt include that, split by System and Day! So for both systems because I can calculate Utilization rate and compare it..

Comment: Right... but you also want the time difference to cut off at midnight each day? As though you almost need to insert another entry at the end of each day?

Comment: Well thats a thing, I would like to have it exactly for 24h, even if it is gonna be "cut"..but not only to exceed 100% like in my case. Is it feasible or it can be issue because there are different cases also, for example you can have a "gap" for 2 days or similar...

Comment: I think that I am nearly there... the gap is causing an issue though. Is there a max number of days gap?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but from my experience wth this kind of data, it wasnt more than 5-10 consecutive days (sometimes they (company) had system off for some days or due to repair)..  usually is couple of days but NOT often as a case. That depends on the system (I have like 20 systems, and the one I showed is only of 1/20)!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. This may not do exactly what you want but I hope this helps get you there...

You have 3 main static data columns:

- Date
- Start Time
- System

I started by combining the "Date" and "Start Time" into a single "Start Datetime" column.

I then created a "Finish DateTime" column by using `MINIFS` - this way, the sort order of the table will not affect the data.

I then made another column which shows either the finish time, or the end of the day, whichever comes first (`MIN`).

I then calculate the "Total Time Difference" - simply the "Finish Datetime" minus the "Start Datetime".

I do the same again, but this time for the "Midnight Cut Off Finish Time".

The last helper column I have added is to show how much time has passed after the Midnight Cut Off. This is simply the "Total Time Diff" minus the "Midnight Cut Off Time Diff".

All fairly simple so far. Here is an image which will hopefully make my layout clear. (you can move or hide the columns as needed).

[image]

The formulas for these helper columns are quite simple, so I won't explain them but will supply them below:

Start Datetime

```
Start Datetime:
     =$A3+$B3

Finish Datetime:
     =IF(MINIFS($D$3:$D$12,$D$3:$D$12,">"&$D3)=0,"",MINIFS($D$3:$D$12,$D$3:$D$12,">"&$D3))

Finish Time (Midnight Cut Off):
     =IF($E3="","",MIN($A3+1,$E3))

Total Time Diff:
     =IF($E3="","",$E3-$D3)

Time diff (Until Midnight):
     =IF($E3="","",$F3-$D3)

Remaining Time (After Midnight):
     =IF($E3="","",$G3-$H3)
```

**----------------------------------------------------------------**
**EDIT: Clarification in response to comment.**
**----------------------------------------------------------------**

The "Finish Datetime" formula is actually just a single `MINIFS` function.

It looks more complex because I have wrapped it in an `IF` statement to handle the case when there is no finish time (i.e. we are currently in that time period).

In that case, to avoid it returning "01/01/1900" (0), it returns an empty string instead.

So the main `MINIFS` function:

```
MINIFS($D$3:$D$12,$D$3:$D$12,">"&$D3)
```

Works by selecting the smallest "Start Datetime" which is greater than the "Start Datetime". (i.e. the next start time along.)

If your data is always sorted by ascending "Start Datetime", you could accomplish the same thing by simply `=$D4` (i.e. selecting the Start Datetime of the row below). However, if you then sorted your data differently, it would completely screw up your results.

I always prefer to make tables "Sort Safe".

**----------------------------------------------------------------**
**END EDIT**
**----------------------------------------------------------------**

Also, as you can see, I have added a completely separate table at the end.

This has a list of ALL dates (even those skipped over in the main data) on the left.
And a list of all systems running horizontally (two columns per system to show time and percentage).

The percentage is simply the time for that particular system, divided by the total for that particular day.

The difficult part is working out the Time. The formula to do so is as below:

```
=IF($K3=MAX($A$3:$A$12),"",
    MIN( "24:00:00",
        SUMIFS($H$3:$H$12, $A$3:$A$12, $K3, $C$3:$C$12, L$1)
        +
        MAX(0,
            SUMIFS($I$3:$I$12, $D$3:$D$12, MAXIFS($D$3:$D$12, $A$3:$A$12, "<"&$K3, $C$3:$C$12, L$1), $C$3:$C$12, L$1)
            -
            (   $K3
                -IF(MAXIFS($A$3:$A$12,$A$3:$A$12,"<"&$K3)=0, $K3, MAXIFS($A$3:$A$12,$A$3:$A$12,"<"&$K3)+1)
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The first part, checks that there is a finish time for the date in question, and if not, returns a blank.

The `MIN("24:00:00", ...` limits the amount of time to 24 hours. I.E. if multiple days are skipped, any more than one is ignored (for this particular date).

The rest of the formula is basically:

```
<Total time diff up until midnight for the particular date & system>
+
<The time remaining after midnight from the day before>
-
<The number of days skipped>
```

If you have any queries, please let me know.

Comment: I will have a deeper look later when done with another task that I am doing right now, but seems fair! A bit different approach from mine. But the only thing that caught my eye is that last Table where systems are - how the percentages are the same for both systems? 

As I say I must and will go thoroughly bit later when get home to see in details, thats the only thing for now I saw. 

You did great job, that time difference will be useful definetly!

Comment: Ooops. Sorry. Ignore that. Just a silly error copying and pasting my percentage formula. I have fixed the image now.

Comment: Great! Will write it till end of the day my test! I will keep you informed!

Comment: This [Finish Datetime] column is bothering me...I am just now trying after concatenating date/time the "IF" statement but it doesnt work, gives me zeros. Can you copy/paste whole functions or to check it for mistype? It is a lot of If statements through this example.

Comment: Please see my edit for explanation. Please also make sure that all your dates and times, are actually stored as date, not text that looks like a date. When you say "concatenating date/time", generally `CONCATENATE` is a string function. Just be sure that you are adding the time to the date, rather than appending the time to the end of a date string. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry for late response...was off for couple of days. Anyways, check my Edited SS that I updated - it is not working actually, that part with "Finish DateTime", gives always blanks.

Comment: Are you sure that both, your "Date" & "Time" columns are actually stored as dates? And not just text?

Comment: Yes...I know that already that they need to be in certain format....could it be because of regional settings or something? I dont think so but still..

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what could be the problem then. Do your settings allow dates with a dot instead of a slash (mine dont)? If you change the format of the columns to "number", what values do they show?

Comment: Will check it at evening...unfortunately here at Work they dont have Office 365 and MINIFS function :/   but I might try to change Date format @home. Strange that it didnt work.

Comment: Can you use aggregate instead?: `=AGGREGATE(15,6,$D$3:$D$12/($D$3:$D$12>$D3),1)`

Comment: That works, but there is another issue...just realised. It makes error/repeatings when it goes into another month...
check the SS please! Up till then works good I think.

Comment: And btw., Your calculated field "Total time difference" is the same as mine TIme difference...I used =MOD function, gave the same result as yours.

Comment: I am sorry, without being able to see and investigate what is going wrong, it is very hard for me to debug it for you. Is it possible for you to share the actual workbook? My time diff and your time diff *should* be the same... if not, one of them would be wrong. You can keep using your `MOD` formula if you wish, it's just that $E3-$D3 is much easier for me to understand than having to deal with a `MOD`

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aq7b0zpSsPxdjAtgwcrqLXGNVgal?e=NfxARy

Here you have it on @onedrive 

You will see what I did and what is my issue.

Comment: On second sheet maybe you will not see "scroll bar" (because of protected view or validity) that connects table, dynamically changing chart per month. There you can see over 100% columns.

Comment: No problem. I will take a look and see what I can do as soon as I get chance.

Comment: any chance you looked at the data set I provide some weeks ago??

Comment: Sorry, I haven't. I have been pretty busy since then. I will take a look when I get chance.